# Illegal input exception during evaluation of a postfix expression, when my input more than two numbers

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

I got most of the code out of the text book and every thing seems to be working. For example if I have the postfix 5 2 + it would give me 7, which is correct but if I have 5 2 4 * / 7 - then it throws the illegal input exception. When I got rid of the illegal input exception, it works but doesn't give the right answer.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

//Here is my class and main method 


public class postFix {

    public static final Pattern UNSIGNED_DOUBLE = Pattern.compile("((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))([Ee][-+]?\\d+)?.*?");
    public static final Pattern CHARACTER = Pattern.compile("\\S.*?");


      public static Double postfixEvaluate (String expression) {

          Stack<Double> numbers = new Stack<Double>( );   //Stack for numbers
          Stack<Character> operators = new Stack<Character>( );  //Stack for ops

          Scanner input = new Scanner(expression);
          String next;

          while (input.hasNext())            //Iterator is used (hasNext)
          {
              if (input.hasNext(UNSIGNED_DOUBLE))
              {  // if next input is a number
                  next = input.findInLine(UNSIGNED_DOUBLE);
                  numbers.push(new Double(next));  //adding nums to the number stack
              }

              else
                  {  //The next input is an operator

                  next = input.findInLine(CHARACTER);

                  switch (next.charAt(0))
                  {
                      case '+':
                      case '-':
                      case '*':
                      case '/':
                          operators.push(next.charAt(0));  //adding operators to operator stack
                          break;
                      case ')':
                          evaluateStackTops(numbers, operators);
                          break;
                      case '(':
                          break;
                     default:  //Illegal Character
                       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Character");
                  }
              }
          }

//This what seems to be throwing the exception but I got this right out of the book

        if (numbers.size() != 1)

              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Input");

          return numbers.pop( );
      }

      public static void evaluateStackTops (Stack<Double> numbers, Stack<Character> operators)
      {
          double operand1 , operand2;

          //check that the stacks have enough items, and get the two operands
          if ((numbers.size()<2)||(operators.isEmpty())) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Expression");}
              operand2 = numbers.pop();
              operand1 = numbers.pop();

          //carry out an operation based on the operator on top of the stack

         for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
              switch (operators.pop()) {
                  case '+':
                      numbers.push(operand1 + operand2);
                      break;
                  case '-':
                      numbers.push(operand1 - operand2);
                      break;
                  case '*':
                      numbers.push(operand1 * operand2);
                      break;
                  case '/':
                      numbers.push(operand1 / operand2);
                      break;
                  default:
                      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Operator");
              }
          }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String expression;
        //Scanner input = new Scanner(expression);

        System.out.println(postFix.postfixEvaluate("(2  3  5  *  /  )" ));

    }
}
```

Comment: if you change !=1 to <=1, would it work?

Comment: No, it seems like its not reading all the numbers and operators in the stacks. I have no idea why it wouldn't though, unless I'm missing something

Comment: What answer are you expecting? Does `5 2 4 * / 7 -` represent the infix expression `(5 / (2 * 4)) - 7`?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is flawed. All it does is build stacks of operators and operands, and then evaluate the expression backwards. That's never going to work.

I don't understand why you're even checking for parentheses. There are no parentheses in postfix expressions, because the conversion from infix to postfix has already removed the parentheses.

Also, there is no need for a stack of operators. The whole idea of postfix is that you can evaluate each operator as you encounter it, and push the result back onto the stack.

The basic algorithm is:

```
while not end of input
    read next token
    if token is a number
        push on numbers stack
    else if token is operator
        pop value2 and value1 from stack
        result = evaluate value1 <operator> value2
        push result to numbers stack
    else
        invalid input
end while
// at this point, there should be 1 value on numbers stack
```

So when evaluating `5 2 4 * / 7 -`, the sequence is:

```
push 5
push 2
push 4
// operator * read here
pop 4
pop 2
evaluate 2 * 4
push 8
// operator / read here
pop 8
pop 5
evaluate 5/8
push 0.625
push 7
// operator - read here
pop 7
pop 0.625
evaluate 0.625 - 7
push -6.375
// end of input here
pop final result
```

Comment: Thank you so much! makes a lot of sense.